# wifi problem card rt3290

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp, realtek

my WiFi card doesn't work no mater what Linux distro i use but on win10 it works fine the card is WiFi Bluetooth combo the Bluetooth part doesn't work at all .i tried  using an external WiFi and also dosn't work .[this what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlSau.png)

[the drivers seems to be working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJQNb.png)

[the bleutooth is not showing at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOL3D.png)

here are some infos  https://pastebin.com/raw/7UP4RTtV

Comment: Turn on wifi on the wifi settings window.  Bluetooth might not ever work

Comment: i tried it nothing happens